# Nginx, Forge, WordPress(roots): No input file specified

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, server, forge

My WordPress site started showing "No input file specified." and it has been working for years now
[image: Error for the website]

The WordPress site is on a subdomain of the main site. EG https://example.com/_wp
[[image: Nginx configuration on Laravel Forge (https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UjLO.png)]/

I have restarted the server, updated the Nginx configuration, and tried setting it up again still the same error.